# Will SameSite=None cookie be deprecated in the future?

Tags: cookies, chromium, setcookie, samesite, httpcookie

I am creating a feature that will heavily depend upon cookies with SameSite=None and secure flag set to true as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

> Cookies with SameSite=None must now also specify the Secure attribute (they require a secure context/HTTPS).

This currently works on all modern browsers.

Is there any speculation that these cookies will be deprecated in the (near) future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh they're trying very hard to destroy 3rd party cookies altogether. Not sure if yours are third party or not.

https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/building-more-private-web-path-towards.html

"we plan to phase out support for third-party cookies in Chrome. Our intention is to do this within two years"

Already every other Chrome update destroys integrations between sites that depend on the samesite behavior you mention.

This checkin reverted behavior to a more tolerant samesite behavior because a previous samesite change broke so many sites. but it won't last for long. They will re-add it in the future.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/fdfe7482acbb6a4f5605103ce7d2956e2336e27e

Comment: The linked change on Google Git talks about when a navigation is considered cross-site, but does it also change the interpretation of the `SameSite` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to combine it with the "Partitioned" attribute for it to still work after ~Q1 2024:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Partitioned_cookies#browser_compatibility

At this time partitioned cookies are still experimental.

Answer (score 0):

`SameSite=None` has two effects, which should be distinguished:

- It allows a cookie in requests made to one site while running in an HTML page from another site (for example, from an iframe embedded in that page, or from a Javascript `fetch` statement executed on that page).
- It allows a cookie in *navigation requests* from one site to another where the target site is loaded into a top-level browsing context (opening a new tab or replacing the URL of the current tab). Without `SameSite=None`, such cookies are blocked in POST navigation requests, but still allowed in GET navigation requests, this behavior is called `Lax`. (`SameSite=Strict` blocks cookies in all cross-site navigation requests, but see [SameSite=Strict cookies and cross-site requests with redirections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184259/samesite-strict-cookies-and-cross-site-requests-with-redirections).)

I would expect the first effect to be abolished (for non-partitioned cookies) when browser vendors start blocking third-party cookies, but not the second.