# SameSite=Strict cookies and cross-site requests with redirections

Tags: redirect, cookies, samesite

Cross-site requests do not include same-site cookies, but what happens if such a request leads to a redirection within the target site?

I tested this with the following Node.js express app running on `https://site-a.com`:

```js
app.get("/a", function(req, res) {
  res.cookie("a", "b", {sameSite: "strict", secure: true, httpOnly: true});
  res.end();
})
.get("/b", function(req, res) {
  res.end(req.get("Cookie"));
})
.get("/c", function(req, res) {
  res.redirect("/b");
})
.get("/d", function(req, res) {
  res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body onload="location.href='/b'"></body></html>`);
});
```

and an HTML page `https://site-b.com` that contains cross-site hyperlinks to `https://site-a.com/b`, `https://site-a.com/c` and `https://site-a.com/d`.

I performed the following steps with Google Chrome (version 109.0.5414.75):

1. Go to `https://site-a.com/a` in a browser window. This sets the same-site cookie.
2. Open the HTML page at `https://site-b.com`.
3. Clicking the `/b` link does not send the same-site cookie.
4. Clicking the `/c` link does not send the same-site cookie, neither with the first request `GET /c` (which leads to an HTTP redirection) nor with the second request `GET /b` that results from the redirection.
5. Clicking the `/d` link does not send the same-site cookie with the first request `GET /d` (which serves an HTML page), but *does* send it with the second request `GET /b` that results from the Javascript redirection in the HTML page.

I am surprised by the difference in behavior between steps 4 (HTTP redirection) and 5 (Javascript redirection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is explained by criterion 3 in the [definition of same-site](https://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis.html#same-site-requests). A same-site cookie is sent in a request whose [client](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-client) has the same origin as its URL. In the given example, this means that the request's client must have origin `https://site-b.com` for the cookie to be sent.

- The request's client of the HTTP-redirected request in step 4 is still `https://site-a.com`, because the request's client does not change during an [HTTP-redirect fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-http-redirect-fetch%E2%91%A0).
- The request's client of the Javascript-redirected request in step 5 is `https://site-b.com`, because an HTML page from that origin has been loaded and the second request is a second [scheme fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-http-fetch%E2%91%A4), not an HTTP-redirect fetch.