# Why is Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site when redirecting to same-site

Tags: cors, same-origin-policy, samesite, sec-fetch-site, sec-fetch-mode

Flow:

1. GET https://abc.example.com:8445/desktop/container (protected resource, redirect for saml authentication) response 302
2. GET https://xyx.test.com:8553 - does saml authentication and redirects (302) to https://abc.example.com:8445/desktop/sso/authcode
3. https://abc.example.com:8445/desktop/sso/authcode - responds with auth tokens in response cookies (same-site:strict) and redirects (302) to original request (https://abc.example.com:8445/desktop/container)
4. https://abc.example.com:8445/desktop/container - (token cookies are not sent in request hence again initiating saml authentication again)

Here in 4th request, I am expecting token cookies to be sent in request but they are not sent actually and Request Header set by browser `Sec-Fetch-Dest: document Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site`

Why Sec-Fetch-Site is cross-site? This (point 3 and 4) seems same-origin request.

If I set same-site: none for response cookies of 3rd request then it works fine i.e, these cookies are sent for the 4th request.

Comment: From where are you calling `https://abc.example.com:8445/desktop/container`? Some browser-based client? If so, what is it's Web origin?

Comment: yes I am using chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking https://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78195772 makes three requests:

1. To `httpbin.org`, this is a cross-site navigation and therefore has `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site`.
2. To `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78195772`, this is caused by the `302 Found` response to the first request and therefore inherits its `Sec-Fetch-Site` header.
3. To `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78195772/why-is-sec-fetch-site-cross-site-when-redirecting-to-same-site`, this is caused by the `301 Moved Permanently` response to the second request and therefore inherits its `Sec-Fetch-Site` header.

The `Sec-Fetch-Site` header is "inherited" by the second and third request, because these are [HTTP-redirect fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-http-redirect-fetch%E2%91%A0) requests. It would be different if the redirection was triggered by a Javascript statement such as

```js
location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78195772";
```

because this would lead to a [scheme fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-http-fetch%E2%91%A4) request. In that case, the transition from request #1 to #2 would be cross-site, and the transition from request #2 to #3 would be same-site.

(See also [SameSite=Strict cookies and cross-site requests with redirections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184259/samesite-strict-cookies-and-cross-site-requests-with-redirections))