Samesite strict and redirects within the same domain
Our policy was set to samesite = strict and most everything was working.
However one SSO (openId) login was not playing nicely.
User starts at ourdomain.com/login, hits the SSO button and gets redirected to azuredomain.com and logs in.
azuredomain.com redirects back to our ssoprocessing.com which processes the token exchange, and sorts out login tokens etc.
ssoprocessing.com then redirects to ourdomain.com/login which checks tokens and creates a session cookie.
ourdomain.com/login then redirects to the final dashboard page where they should be logged in, however the session is lost during the final redirect from ourdomain.com/login to ourdomain.com/dashboard.
Why is that, the cookie is being set on the same domain and this exact same process works for other openId sso logins, also with azure but different tenants.
all works fine when samesite=lax.
Its confusing me (not hard), not least because other SSO implementations work ok using the same code/flow
Thanks all

Sounds as if ourdomain.com/login receives a Set-Cookie header but blocks the cookie and hence does not send it with the redirection to ourdomain.com/dashboard. Do the browser DevTools > Network tab indicate problems with this Set-Cookie header?

thanks for the reply. This still happens if I change it so that the sso processing is on the same domain so; ourdomain.com/login > azuredomain > ourdomain.com/sso > ourrdomain.com/login. All the ourdomain responses set a secure cookie (Strict or lax)

SameSite=strict means, the cookie will not be send with requests originating from outside your domain. The request to ourdomain.com/sso is initiated from the outside. The question would now be, if you redirect from there, within the domain - should that be considered a request originating from your domain, or still from the outside? I think it should be the latter, because otherwise, I could easily circumvent this restriction with a malicious link that I know will cause a redirect - like f.e. target the http version of a URL which I know will be redirected to its https version ...

@C3roe: Regarding SameSite=strict and redirections, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184259/samesite-strict-cookies-and-cross-site-requests-with-redirections.
